# How to Handle closing of outlook Mail Window(Desktop App) window and switch back to web application in selenium using java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, outlook

After ALT+ F4 control is not going to the Pop up window.

```
public void emailVerification() throws Exception {
    Boolean is_EmailLinkPresent = isElementPresentClass(email locator);
    if (is_EmailLinkPresent) {
        Boolean is_EmailLinkClickable = isClickableByClass(email locator);
        if (is_EmailLinkClickable){
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F4);
        }                           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium does not handle desktop applications. You'll have to look at integrating AutoIT and have your Selenium automated script call the AutoIT script to handle desktop applications.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I have one other question also.Is`nt Robo class do the same desktop application handling as same as Auto IT.

Comment: In Single window I m am able to do the action in outlook.But on Popup which appears after alt +f4 I am facing problem to perform action on that.